# Regex to match only strings ending with a specific word and not containing other words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I tried to make a regex to match a string ending with the word 'Remixes' but only when it is not preceded by certain words and characters. I came up with the following regex with different results but both doesn't match it perfectly:

```
^(\w+)((?!\&|\+|And|The|Of|Various|House|Unreleased|Selected).)\s(Remixes)$
```

This excludes all the keywords in the string but not when it contains multiple words like: *Think Twice Remixes* or when it has one preceding word like: *Various Remixes*

```
^(.*)((?!\&|\+|And|The|Of|Various|House|Unreleased|Selected).)\s(Remixes)$
```

This excludes the following testexample: *Fill Me Up + Remixes* but not other examples with the excluded keywords, like *Sides & Remixes*

How can i make the first string match string with multiple preceding words and not match it if the exclude word is the only and first preceding word?

Comment: Does it have to be a single regex? Because honestly, this is the kind of job that whilst you can _probably_ do it, the solution is MUCH less ugly if you actually use a script.

Comment: I think you can use `^(?!.*(?:&|\+|\b(?:And|The|Of|Various|House|Unreleased|Selected)\b)).*\bRemixes$`

Comment: I tried this but it does not match the keywords and does not have a group for the preceding words that i want to keep. I dont see where to specify the group for that either

Comment: Are you looking for a lookbehind? Have a try at [regex101 with this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/eU2lN8/2) (add `i` flag if not case sensitive).

Comment: @bobblebubble This is perfect! I added a grouping to make it usable for me. Thanks for your help.
 
^(.+)(?<!\&|\+|And|The|Of|Various|House|Unreleased|Selected)\s(Remixes)$

Comment: @Wouter You're welcome. Added it as an answer with your grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wouldn't. `regex` is a powerful tool, and you can do a lot of things with it, but your code becomes much simpler and clearer when you don't try to "single-regex" every problem.

For your example, I would be quite tempted to use perl's `grep` function, which lets you specify compound conditions:

```
 my @filtered = grep { m/Remixes$/ 
                     and not   
                        m/(And
                             |The
                             |Of
                             |Various
                             |House
                             |Unreleased
                             |Selected
                         )\s*.?\s+Remixes/xi } @list_of_things
```

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#set up a list of words to exclude when prefixing "Remix"
#qw is perl's "quote words" and lets you specify whitespace delimited values. 
my @exclude_remix_prefix = qw ( And
    The
    Of
    Various
    House
    Unreleased
    Selected );

#turn that into a sub regex (qr 'compiles' a regex). 
my $exclude = join( "|", @exclude_remix_prefix );
$exclude = qr/($exclude)\s+Remixes/i;

#read from the <DATA> filehandle, 
#but you could use <> to read from STDIN/filenames like 'sed/grep' do. 
my @filtered = grep { m/Remixes$/i and not m/$exclude/i; } <DATA>;

print @filtered;

__DATA__
Fill Me Up + Remixes
Sides & Remixes
Something Selected remixes
```

Output:

```
Fill Me Up + Remixes
Sides & Remixes
```

(Give me some samples of what should/shouldn't be matched, and I will expand)

We're probably straying a bit from your original use case, but if you want to create a transform pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @exclude_remix_prefix = qw ( And
    The
    Of
    Various
    House
    Unreleased
    Selected );

my $exclude = join( "|", @exclude_remix_prefix );
$exclude = qr/($exclude)\s+Remixes/i;

my %transform = map { m/$exclude/ ? () :  m/(.*)/ =>  m/(.*)\s+Remixes/ ; } <DATA>;
print Dumper \%transform; 

__DATA__
Euterpeh Remixes
The Beauty And The Beast Remixes
Think Twice Remixes
Stop And Reset Remixes
```

This generates specifically a hash containing:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'The Beauty And The Beast Remixes' => 'The Beauty And The Beast',
          'Think Twice Remixes' => 'Think Twice',
          'Euterpeh Remixes' => 'Euterpeh',
          'Stop And Reset Remixes' => 'Stop And Reset'
        };
```

Which you could perhaps use to generate a sequence of rename operations?

Or if you just want to 'in place' some operation, then a `for` loop:

```
for ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp; 
    next if m/$exclude/; 
    print "rename ", m/(.*)\s+Remixes/, " ", m/(.*)/,"\n";
}
```

(OK, I know 'rename' isn't quite what you want to do, but ...)

Comment: Thank you for your work, unfortunately the program i use (MP3tag) only supports single regex's. I can make separate regex's but that's as far as it goes. The example input and desired output is the following:

Comment: `grep` is filtering the list to include/exclude things that match your pattern. You can do something very similar with `map` if you need to transform your matches as well. But I would need an example of input and desired output.

Comment: Examples to match:

*Euterpeh Remixes*, *The Beauty And The Beast Remixes*, *Think Twice Remixes*, *Stop And Reset Remixes* to change to (.*) (Remixes)